# Testing List<byte[]> for equality

Tags: java, testing, testng

I'm using TestNG for unit testing and now I have a method to test which return `List<byte[]>`. Here is how my test looks like now:

```
public List<byte[]> methodToTest(){
   //...
}

@Test
public void test(){
    List<byte[]> expected;
    //...
    Assert.assertEquals(methodToTest(), expected); //now fails
}
```

The question is if it possible to tell TestNG to perform `List` content comparison (`byte[]` in my case) with not just `equals`, but with `Arrays.equals`?

Or I will have to iterate through the `List` and perform comparison of every element myself?

Comment: Calling `equals` on a `byte[]` will be the same as using `==` and will mostly fail. You'll need to call `Arrays.equals(byteArray1, byteArray2)` for each element on the returned list. I think you'll need to use a loop for this purpose.

Comment: @BackSlash Yes, thats why I ask how to do comparison with `Arrays.equals`, not just `equals`

Comment: You need to call [`ArrayAsserts.assertArrayEquals`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.11-g7bc33ff-100/javadoc/org/testng/internal/junit/ArrayAsserts.html) on each element of the list.

Comment: @BackSlash Sad... In ScalaTest for instance we can supply custom "comparator" for testing...

Comment: The thing you can do is write a custom assertion. [Here you can find a tutorial](https://www.testingdocs.com/custom-assertions-testng-framework/). I think you can easily override the method you need to make it do the array comparison too

Comment: If this would be junit, I would simply point to assertThat and hamcrest matchers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Usage

```
assertThat(methodToTest(), deepEqual(expected));
```

copy following code into your tests:

```
Matcher<List<?>> deepEqual(List<?> expected) {
    return new FeatureMatcher<List<?>, List<?>>(equalTo(arrayToList(expected))
                                               ,"items", "") {
        @Override
        protected List<?> featureValueOf(List<?> actual) {
            return arrayToList(actual);
        }
    };
}

static List<?> arrayToList(List<?> it) {
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object item : it) {
        result.add(isArray(item) ? Arrays.asList(array(item)) : item);
    }
    return result;
}

static boolean isArray(Object it) {
    return it != null && it.getClass().isArray();
}

static Object[] array(Object array) {
    int length = Array.getLength(array);
    Object[] result = new Object[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result[i] = Array.get(array, i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

*Note*: you need add [org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.hamcrest%7Chamcrest-all%7C1.3%7Cjar) library into your test classpath.

Answer (score 2):

**Assertion will something like this :**

Assert.assertTrue(Arrays.equals(byteArray1, byteArray2))

Answer (score 0):

TestNG already provides some deep assertions but the one with List param is missing: https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.11-g7bc33ff-100/javadoc/org/testng/Assert.html#assertEqualsDeep-java.util.Map-java.util.Map-